# BIML OLE DB connection uses the wrong database (sometimes)

Tags: sql-server, oledb, biml

I'm using BIML to interrogate the schema of the source and destination databases, check that everything is configured correctly, and then generate a bunch of SSIS packages. My issues is that occasionally the OLE DB connection starts using the Master system database instead of the one I've specified in the connection string. I can tell it is the master database by examining the tables that get returned.

I define the connection using BIML markup:

```
<OleDbConnection Name="appdb" ConnectionString="Server=<#=ReplicationConfig.appdbHostname#>;Database=<#=ReplicationConfig.appdbDatabaseName#>;Integrated Security=SSPI;Provider=SQLNCLI11;" CreateInProject="true" />
```

I've hit the issue mostly when trying to use the `GetDatabaseSchema()` method of the OleDbConnection object on the BIML root node. Though I have also run across it when trying to use an Execute SQL task. It was easy to work around with the Execute SQL task because I could fully qualify the table with `[DatabaseName].[schema].[Table]` but I don't have that option with the `GetDatabaseSchema()` method. I've also tried using `ImportDB()` and `GetTableNodes()` and they both experience the same issue.

When trying to migrate my solution from the development environment to test the issue has cropped up again. In the past this has been fixed by restarting Visual Studio (or working around it in the SQL query). However, that hasn't worked this time.

I'm using BIML Express with Visual Studio 2015.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong or how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working around the issue by setting the default database for my login to the one that I needed to work with. For some reason BIML seems to be ignoring the database specified in the connection string.